# trying to plot three lines using Amchart, but lines are not drawn

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I am new to amchart. Trying to plot three lines in a graph where x-axis is time stamp with month-day hour:seconds format (HH-dd HH:s).

any kind of help will be appreciated.
setting time like this:

```
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "MM-dd HH:S";
```

Here is the link to the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/azaman13/dymhbjk1/4/

Comment: it doesn't solve your issue, but series.dataFields.dateX = "date"; <-- your data does not contain a field date, you named it 'data'

Comment: thats good catch. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: So it is what you doing wrong, you should set dataFields.dateX = "data" and not "date"